# resizing of images in corona sdk for ipad and iphone

Tags: lua, coronasdk

is there any possibility in corona sdk that we write one code for paticular application and it can be run on both ipad and iphone, without changing the coordinates of objects and sizes of images for both devices seperately?
Can it be possible through display.contentHeight and display.contentWidth?

Answer (score 2):

Mud was basically correct. By setting the content width/height, Corona SDK will draw and scale your app on the iPhone / iPad (+retina) screens automatically. The best way to think of it is to design your app on a 320x480 screen - and then provide images for that screen size. You then create a 2nd set of images for the larger screens. By using Corona's display.newImageRect() it will load your small images for iPhone, and then the larger resolutio images on the iPad / retina displays.

Take a look at this article: http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/03/12/understanding-letterbox-scalling

Your config.lua should look like this:

```
application = {
    content = {
        width = 320,
        height = 480,
        scale = "letterbox",
        xAlign = "center",
        yAlign = "center",

        imageSuffix = {
            ["@2x"] = 2
            ["@4x"] = 4
        },
    },
}
```

When you call display.contentHeight and display.contentWidth, you are simply reading those values from the config.lua file. I tend to use some global variables if I need to do any specific positioning calculations. Define these in your main.lua:

```
screenWidth = display.contentWidth - (display.screenOriginX*2)
screenHeight = display.contentHeight - (display.screenOriginY*2)
screenTop = display.screenOriginY
screenRight = display.contentWidth - display.screenOriginX
screenBottom = display.contentHeight - display.screenOriginY
screenLeft = display.screenOriginX
screenCenterX = display.contentWidth/2
screenCenterY = display.contentHeight/2
```

For example:

```
companyLogo = display.newImageRect("companyLogo.png",64,64)
```

You will need 1 64x64px image named companyLogo.png. This will be for < iPhone 4. You then need a 128x128px image named companyLogo@2x.png. Corona will use this automatically on the iPhone 4 and iPad. Again, another image that's 256x56 named companyLogo@4x.png will be used on the iPad 3 retina display.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. For example, if your app is written for 640x480, you can have it automatically scale to other resolutions by telling it *how* you want it scaled in your `config.lua` file:

```
application =
{
        content =
        {
                width = 640,
                height = 480,
                scale = "letterbox"
        },
}
```

[More info.](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/configuring-projects#Dynamic_Content_Scaling)

Comment: Hi Mud! Thanks for reply but i am in doubt.If i am developing same app for ipad and iphone4 then it might not possible that coordinates and image sizes adjust automatically.Please clear it.

Comment: [Here's Corona's documentation on this subject.](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/configuring-projects#Dynamic_Content_Scaling) Internally this stuff is all OpenGL. If Corona knows the dimensions of your app, it's trivial to scale it up or down to any resolution. The `scale` flag just tells it what to do when the aspect ratio of the display doesn't match the aspect ratio of your app.